# Is it possible to create an HDMI input adapter for android?

Tags: android, hdmi

Would it be possible to stream a video signal **into** an android device? I understand that the HDMI port it's self is not designed to take input, so I was thinking that the data could be streamed via the USB port. I know that the Apple hardware prohibits this (apple made this decision for some reason) but would it be feasible on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get USB capture devices that will take HDMI video in and encode it to e.g. H264. You can get Android devices that can USB master. So then it's a matter of drivers. It looks like it's doable if you can choose the device and supply your own kernel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334612/analog-video-capture-to-android-phone

Comment: I believe the android device
 has to be at least android 3.1 to support USB master.

Answer (score 1):

This would rather be solved using any normal network streaming sending in the video signal via wlan. 
So the solution would be to either use media server that gives this video stream or service that takes any HDMI input and sends it as a H264 compress network stream.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. DJI makes a device for streaming 1080p from a quadcopter called LIGHTBRIDGE. On the receiver they have a plug that goes HDMI to USB to display video feed on an Android phone or tablet.

I don't know the protocol they use.

Comment: It's a pretty fair bit that they're compressing the stream with something like H264, and outputting that over USB. There's not really a way to pass a actual HDMI signal over the USB interface.